# Excel with 3 paramaters

Tags: excel, if-statement

Getting really desperate out here! I've read pretty much all the threads on this topic here but nothing seems to be working.

So, I need an IF function that would incorporate the following:

- if b3=1, "Overbought"
- if b3=2, "Neutral"
- if b3=-1, "Oversold"

As said, I have tried few things such as nested IF functions but it always returns two of the three!!

Thanks a lot and I look forward to hearing from you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really I think it's a job for `CHOOSE` as nested `IF`s are difficult to read.

Consider therefore

```
=CHOOSE(B3 + 2, "Oversold", "", "Overbought", "Neutral")
```

The `+ 2` is required since `CHOOSE` requires the choices to be based on the values of the first parameter starting from 1. If `B3` is 0 then the resulting cell is set to a blank string.

Comment: Amazing! thanks so much!

Comment: This looks like a v useful function going forward- could you tell me abit more about why the "" is required? If at all possible would be great if you could explain how it works in general in a biot more detail

Comment: Lots of chat on https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/choose-function-fc5c184f-cb62-4ec7-a46e-38653b98f5bc

Answer (score 0):

Bathsheba's answer should work well enough but if you insist on using if:

```
=IF(B3=1;"Overbought";IF(B3=2;"Neutral";"Oversold"))
```